# react-native-reanimated sharedTransitionTag is not available in nested navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated

I'm working on a React Native project and using react-native-reanimated version 3.4.2. Why is the sharedTransitionTag not working in nested navigation, any idea?